# Adding a jar file from libs/ to Android.mk

Tags: android, android-make

I *almost* found the answer in [Adding a external jar reference in Android.mk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598293) but I'm still not quite there.

My project contains commons-io-2.4.jar and jsch-0.1.49.jar in the libs/ directory.  Everything builds beautifully in eclipse.  Now I want to write an Android.mk file to build my project automatically.

My Android.mk looks like this, but it's not working.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyProject
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := jsch-0.1.49 commons-io-2.4

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAGS      := -include $(LOCAL_PATH)/proguard.flags

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libs
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libs:jsch-0.1.49 libs:commons-io-2.4

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

I'm sure there's just a little secret sauce I've gotten wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Is there a good reference for Android.mk files?  All I could find were recipes for working with the ndk.

Comment: You can find a good reference regarding how AOSP build system works: http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_cookbook.html

Comment: Above link no longer works.

Comment: https://wladimir-tm4pda.github.io/porting/build_cookbook.html might be the same thing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK, a couple hours of googling and experimenting seems to have found the solution.
Documenting it here for others to find:

The key was to

1. Define `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` with a symbolic name for the library I want to include, e.g. `libjsch`
2. Execute `CLEAR_VARS` (why?)
3. Define `LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` as `libjsch:<path-to-jar-file>`
4. Include `BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT`.

(Testing showed that any symbolic name (e.g. "foo") works fine, as long as it matches in the two declarations.)

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyProject

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libjsch

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libjsch:libs/jsch-0.1.49.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: how can I add .aar files in android.mk ?

Comment: @ofskyMohsen It's the same process as this answer, just replace `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` with `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES`

Comment: can you please say how to import libjsch:libs like import .....?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks a ton Edward Falk. I have just resolved my problem with answer u have given me thanks again  here is my code. The Keyword "lib" is a night mare.

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MDM

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libandroid-async-http libgcm libjson-simple


LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES += telephony-common mms-common

LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libandroid-async-http:libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar libgcm:libs/gcm.jar  libjson-simple:libs/json-simple-1.1.1.jar 

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: can you please say how to import json-simple like import .....?