# How to include constraint layout library in an AOSP project

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-source, android.mk

I have an existing android application that I'd like to build inside AOSP (android source tree) using Android.mk. The app uses constraint layout which is not included in AOSP source tree (AFAIK). 
How can I satisfy this dependency? Other support libs are included such as recyclerview, v4 etc but not contraint layout.

Should I download the lib aar and if yes , how do I add/include it?
Or should I get the source (where to download?) and  build it somewhere in the source tree?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to resolve your issue.

**1. Add a prebuilt .apk**

You don't have to put your source code to the AOSP tree.
You can just add your `.apk` file, put it either in `packages/apps/YourApp`, or `vendor/yourname/packages/apps/YourApp`, or even `your_dir_name/packages/apps/YourApp`, and create an `Android.mk` file for build system to determine your application.

`Android.mk` will look like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := YourApplication # your .apk name
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Pros: you can build your project with `gradle`.

**2. Add source code to AOSP**

If you still want to place your source code to `packages/apps` and build it there, you can put a `ConstrainsLayout` to your project's `libs/` directory and add to your `Android.mk` something like:

```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
  include $(CLEAR_VARS)

  # List of static libraries to include in the package
  LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := constraint-layout

  # Build all java files in the java subdirectory
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

  # Name of the APK
  LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := YourApplication

  # Tell it to build an APK
  include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

In case you will not get it work (I haven't met this issue, [but he did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829473/adding-a-jar-file-from-libs-to-android-mk)):

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libconstraint-layout

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Other stuff, and finally

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := libconstraint-layout:libs/constraint-layout.aar
```

Cons: You will have to build your code either with make by `mma` or `mm -B`, or to have a `gradle` as your second build system for development. The second option will work, but to establish a full build and to have your `.apk` built in `out/` directory you will have to build it with `make`.

**3. Adding a ConstraintLayout**

In case you want to have several applications, which use a constraint layout, you can add it as a new library module as precompiled `.aar`.
Can be somewhere in 'vendor/yourname/libs' or 'your_dir_name/libs' respectively.
It is similar to adding a prebuilt `.apk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := constraint-layout
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).aar
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .aar

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

After that, in your application's `Android.mk` you will have to add:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := constraint-layout
```

Alternatively, you can add a `ConstraintLayout`'s `.aar` to the `prebuilds/` as it eventually will be there someday.

There is a good topic about `Android.mk`: https://wladimir-tm4pda.github.io/porting/build_cookbook.html

Comment: The constraint layout aar can be found here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support.constraint/constraint-layout/1.0.2

Answer (score 3):

From Android 9.0, there is no need of adding `.aar` and `.jar` separately in the project for `constraint-layout`. We can use `constraint-layout` library built in to AOSP.

We need to add one extra line in `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true
```

Then, we need to add:

```
LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay \
    --extra-packages android.support.constraint

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += android-support-constraint-layout

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += android-support-constraint-layout-solver
```

**For more detailed answer: [How to use constraint-layout during AOSP build without including external .aar and .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090643/how-to-use-constraint-layout-during-aosp-build-without-including-external-aar-a/63092141#63092141)**

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46414919/9237859 is right, except `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES` should be used instead of `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES`, since constraint-layout is a aar file.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows:

1. Download constraint-layout.aar and constraint-layout-solve.jar and put these files in lib folder.
2. Add the following to your `Android.mk` file

```
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES += constraint-layout
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += constraint-layout-solver

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := constraint-layout:libs/constraint-layout.aar
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := constraint-layput-solver:libs/constraint-layout-solver.jar
```