# How to add Room,Lifecycle,Paging libraries in Android.mk ( AOSP build)

Tags: android-source, android-lifecycle, android-room, android.mk, android-paging

I created an application with Room,Lifecycle,Paging libraries in android studio,its working well.
Then I tried to build the same application in AOSP,But I can't include Room,Lifecycle,Paging libraries.

I found all these libraries in frameworks/support/ .
But i don't  have any idea about how to add these libraries.

Any clues on how to do it?

Comment: Sounds like a similar question to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413784/how-to-include-constraint-layout-library-in-an-aosp-project

Comment: Did you found any solution for this? @Mad code? If yes, could you please attach your Android.mk?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines in your Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    android-arch-room-runtime \
    android-arch-paging-runtime \
```

Comment: how to include retrofit and other third party libraries in Android.mk  ?  @slfan