# How to use constraint-layout during AOSP build without including external .aar and .jar

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-source, android.mk

I'm trying to build my java based android app through building as a module inside AOSP source. My app uses `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`. But, I didn't find a direct way to include constraint-layout dependency in my `Android.mk`.

I've put my project under `AOSP_ROOT/packages/apps` and tried with this `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true                 
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java) 
LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := AndroidManifest.xml

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay \
    --extra-packages android.support.constraint

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-common \
    android-support-v4 \
    android-support-constraint-layout-solver

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-constraint-layout

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

But, this comes up with build error:

> ninja: error: 'out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/android-support-constraint-layout_intermediates/aar/classes.jar', needed by 'out/target/common/obj/APPS/MyApp_intermediates/AndroidManifest.xml', missing and no known rule to make it
> 20:57:54 ninja failed with: exit status 1

What I understand - it is searching for `classes.jar` which could be built from `.aar` file, but it is missing. However, the answer here solves the issue: [How to include constraint layout library in an AOSP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413784/how-to-include-constraint-layout-library-in-an-aosp-project)

But, the problem is, that answer suggests to add external `constraint-layout.aar` and `constraint-layout-solver.jar` within my project `libs` directory.

My question, is it possible to add `constraint-layout` support in my project using built-in library inside AOSP without adding external `.aar` and `.jar` to my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyways, I've found the solution. There is no need to include the `constraint-layout` in the project `libs` as extra library.

To solve the issue, in `Android.mk` we need to add one extra line:

`LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true`

And also use `LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES` instead of `LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_AAR_LIBRARIES`.

This is the working `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true                 
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApp
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true

LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, java) 
LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := AndroidManifest.xml

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay \
    --extra-packages android.support.constraint

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES:= \
    android-support-constraint-layout

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-common \
    android-support-v4 \
    android-support-constraint-layout-solver

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```