# Android.mk - Adding external java libraries as maven repositories or prebuilt java libraries

Tags: android, android-source, android.mk

I am trying to make my application compile within AOSP instead of using Gradle within Android Studio. I created an `Android.mk` file, however, since my application uses Eclipse Paho library, I do not know how to add it to the AOSP.

Here is the build.gradle from Android Studio:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mozcelikors.mediainthebox.mobile"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/" //MQTT
    }

    // ConstraintLayout
    google()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    /*MQTT*/
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'

    // ConstraintLayout
    compile "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
}
```

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/app/src/main/res
LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := system_current # or current
LOCAL_MIN_SDK_VERSION := 14
LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyLauncher
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES := Home Launcher2 Launcher3 Launcher3Go Launcher3QuickStep

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, app/src)

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled
#LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := ../../proguard-rules.pro

ifeq ($(TARGET_BUILD_APPS),)
support_library_root_dir := frameworks/support
else
support_library_root_dir := prebuilts/sdk/current/support
endif

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR +=   $(support_library_root_dir)/design/res \
                        $(support_library_root_dir)/v7/cardview/res \
                        $(support_library_root_dir)/v7/recyclerview/res \
                        $(support_library_root_dir)/v7/appcompat/res

LOCAL_AAPT_FLAGS := \
    --auto-add-overlay \
    --extra-packages android.support.design \
    --extra-packages android.support.v7.cardview \
    --extra-packages android.support.constraint \
    --extra-packages android.support.v7.recyclerview \
    --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += cr android-common

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := \
    android-support-test \
    mockito-target-inline-minus-junit4 \


LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += androidx.legacy_legacy-support-v4
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += androidx.gridlayout_gridlayout
LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += android-support-constraint-layout android-support-constraint-layout-solver

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    android-support-v4 \
    android-support-v7-appcompat \
    android-support-v7-recyclerview \
    android-support-dynamic-animation

LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Here is the error from AOSP:

```
com/mozcelikors/mediainthebox/mobile/MainActivity.java:28: error: package org.eclipse.paho.android.service does not exist
import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;

com/mozcelikors/mediainthebox/mobile/MyMqttService.java:19: error: package org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 does not exist
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;

...
```

I wonder how can this missing dependency added as maven repository or as a prebuilt java library. Any help in this regard is greately appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829473/adding-a-jar-file-from-libs-to-android-mk

Comment: When I do that, I get: error: MyApplication (java:sdk) can not link against eclipse-paho-client-mqttv3 (java:platform)