# Android runtime linking issue

Tags: android, makefile, embedded-linux, android-build, android-make

I am trying to build an application and an interface jar using the android build system in Linux
My application has a dependency with my interface, hence I have to make interface jar ready before application make.

But we faced build/run time issues while using our newly built interface jar.
I have tried to make the application in two different sequence.

Case 1. Building the interface as local module and linking it with apk as LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES.
Case 2. Building the interface as local module and linking it with apk as LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES.

### Following are the Android.mk files for main and interface.

1.Main Andriod.mk file:
**/source/Android.mk**

=======================================

STACK_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH := $(STACK_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/interface/Android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH := $(STACK_PATH)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/application/Android.mk

=======================================

2.Interface Android.mk :
**/source/interface/Android.mk**

=======================================

LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files, src)

LOCAL_MODULE := MyInterface

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES

LOCAL_JAVA_RESOURCE_DIRS := src

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)

$(call dist-for-goals, droidcore, $(full_classes_jar):MyInterface.jar)

=======================================

### Following are the Android.mk files for application in CASE 1.

Application Android.mk:
**/source/application/Android.mk**

=======================================

TOP_LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApplication

LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := MyInterface

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

=======================================

Build completed successfully .But when trying to run this application, it shows this error.
I/dalvikvm( XXXX): Failed resolving Lcom/test/example/application; interface XXX 'Lcom/test/example/interface;'
W/dalvikvm( XXXX): Link of class 'Lcom/test/example/application;' failed

### Following are the Android.mk files for application in CASE 2.

Application Android.mk
**/source/application/Android.mk**

=======================================

TOP_LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_PATH:= $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(shell (cp $(LOCAL_PATH)/../out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/Interface_intermediates/classes-jarjar.jar $(LOCAL_PATH)/applications/libs/MyInterface.jar ))

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += MyInterface

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := MyApplicationss

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES += MyInterface:libs/MyInterface.jar

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)

=======================================

This resulted in a build error as follows.

**build/core/base_rules.mk:166: * source/applications: MODULE.TARGET.JAVA_LIBRARIES.MyInterface already defined by source/interface.  Stop.**

But when they are built seperately without using the build system, this problem is not there.Also the application runs without error.

---

When the interface was built to Myinterface.jar using the eclipse, and build the application-apk using this
interface jar(by linking statically) in Linux, the application ran smoothly.

Is there any issue in my Android.mk files? Please help

Comment: Where are your app and interface located in the Android tree?  Are you able to build any other code using the Android build system?

Comment: Added our app and source in a seperate folder inside the src/mips-ics.    i.e; src/mips-ics/our-source/app and src/mips-ics/our-source/interface . We have already integrated different kinds of application, which is successfully build and running on the boards. But if we tried to build our own interface as a jar, then we are getting these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have `LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES` between `include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)` and `include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)`

See [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598293/adding-a-external-jar-reference-in-android-mk/11302460#11302460) .

Answer (score -1):

Follow the link for Android Build System Details 
http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_system.html

Comment: Link is broken (kandroid removed great old android doc some time ago), use one from [https://web.archive.org/web/20150512173732/http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_system.html](web.archive.org) or look at http://android.mk/